# Solving a system of two matrix equations of form $XA=BY$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have two matrix equations:

$$\begin{cases} XA_1=B_1Y \\ XA_2=B_2Y \end{cases}$$

where $A_1$, $B_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$ are known invertible square $n\times n$ matrices (and not the degenerate case where $A_1=kA_2$ annd $B_1=kB_2$ where $k$ is some constant), and $X$ and $Y$ are two square $n\times n$ matrices that I would like to solve for.

Is there any way to solve this "system of matrix equations," without explicitly writing out all $2n^2$ scalar equations? Is there any way to solve such equations in MATLAB or Mathematica?

In my specific use case, there can be more than two pairs of $A$, $B$ matrices if that helps, but I feel like that's just over constraining the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations give $X=B_1YA_1^{-1}$ with $B_1YA_1^{-1}=B_2YA_2^{-1}$. So it is enough to solve the last equation. It is of the type $AYB-CYD=E$, which has been studied in many papers, e.g., [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379587903144), or [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379589907088).